# Posting data from textboxes in a txt file

Tags: php, fwrite

I would like to ask you a question regarding my simple program.
I have 6 textboxes (a,b,c,a1,b1,c1).
If my inputs are 1,2,3,4,5,6 the txt document shows only the first three numbers 1,2,3 (a,b,c).

Do you know how to solve this problem? I would like to create a txt file as presented below

a,b,c

a1,b1,c1

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<center>
<form method="post">
a:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="a">,&nbsp;&nbsp; b: <input type="text" name="b">, &nbsp;&nbsp;c: <input type="text" name="c"><br>
a1:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="a1">,&nbsp;&nbsp; b1: <input type="text" name="b1">, &nbsp;&nbsp;c1: <input type="text" name="c1"><br><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
$txt = "data.txt";
if (isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b']) && isset($_POST['c'])) 
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a');
    $txt=$_POST['a'].','.$_POST['b'].','.$_POST['c'];
    fwrite($fh,$txt);
}

elseif (isset($_POST['a1']) && isset($_POST['b1']) && isset($_POST['c1']))
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a');
    $txt=$_POST['a1'].','.$_POST['b1'].','.$_POST['c1'];
    fwrite($fh,$txt);
    fclose($fh);
}

?>
</center></body></html>
```

Thank you very much,
George

Comment: Dear Daniel, 

Thanks very much for your proper reply.
I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used an "elseif" for the a1,b1,c1. Therefore, if the a,b,c inputs have been submitted, the a1,b1,c1's won't be written in the text file. If you want all 6 of them to be written to the file, you'll need to turn that "else if" into an "if".

"Else if" means that if the condition in the "if" returns false, it'll be triggered.